# How can we do backup for aws Dynamodb tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Ex: In AWS RDS ex: mysql, oracle, postgres aws takes snapshots automatically(backups)

What about No-sql databases like Dynamodb tables. Is there any alternative way to back it up.

Any ideas or alternatives folks

Comment: @Mark B Thanks for directing me to answer

Comment: Link was placed above original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630641/backup-aws-dynamodb-to-s3